# Testing Windows user accounts without actually logging into them?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, user-accounts

We setup Windows users accounts with redirected profiles here at work, and in the past we have just logged in to the account to test them out. However, recently there has been a change in company policy that as the system administrator I am not allowed to log in to a user's account without the user being present (digitally or physically); even if it's a blank and new account.

How can I test that their account is being correctly redirected without logging into it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Q:How can I test that their account is being correctly redirected without logging into it?

A: You can't. You'll have to test it with the user present.

There's no way to test whether or not GPO, Folder Redirection, Roaming Profiles, etc. actually work correctly for the user without logging in as the user. You could certainly run GP Modeling from the GPMC to check that the right GPO's would be applied but there's no way to confirm that without actually logging in.